# Data property with d2rq

Tags: eclipse, owl, ontology, d2rq

I am using the D2RQ Language to create the mapping file. I have a class Persona with this defination:

```
# Table persone
map:Persona a d2rq:ClassMap;
    d2rq:dataStorage map:database;
    d2rq:uriPattern "persona/@@persona.cognome_persona@@";
    d2rq:class prova_rules_M:Persona;
    .
```

I would like to create a data_property called "anni_persona" for this class. How can I do? Can anyone help me with the syntax?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Properties don't "belong" to classes in RDF or OWL.  Instead, properties may have domains and ranges, which specifies that the subject or object of a triple with the property belongs to a certain class or datatype.  E.g., if we say that the domain of hasName is Agent, then whenever we see "x hasName {something}", then we can infer that "x rdf:type Agent".  It sounds like you're trying to say there is a property anni_persona, and that its domain is Persona.  That's just a matter of asserting **anni_persona rdfs:domain Persona** somewhere.

Now, to get values from the database table into RDF data, I think that you'll just want to take a look at section 6 in the documentation:

> ### [6. Adding properties to resources (d2rq:PropertyBridge)](http://d2rq.org/d2rq-language#propertybridge).
>
> A `d2rq:PropertyBridge` relates a database column to an RDF property.
>   Property bridges are used to attach properties to the RDF resources
>   created by a class map. The values of these properties are often
>   literals, but can also be URIs or blank nodes that relate the resource
>   to other resources, e.g. the value of a paper's `:author` property could
>   be a URI representing a person.
>
> If the one of the columns used in a property bridge is `NULL` for some
>   database rows, then no property is created for the resources
>   corresponding to these rows.

Based on the examples in that documentation, it looks like you'd end up with something like:

```
map:AnniPersona a d2rq:PropertyBridge ;
    d2rq:belongsToClassMap map:Persona ;
    d2rq:property :anni_persona ;
    d2rq:column "Persone.Anni" .
```